# Error parsing undefined value. Path '', line 0, position 0.when serializing anonymous type in windows phone 8 development

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net

Here is my code..

```
var signUpData = new
{
   first = "abcd",
   last ="efgh",
   email ="sometext",
   password = "sometext",
   phone = contactSession.ContactNumber,
   dialing_code = "some",
   country = "some"
};

JsonBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(signUpData);

var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<string, bool>>();

tcs.SetResult(new Tuple<string, bool>(request.ResponseBody,false));//request.ResponseBody is jsonbody that comes from server.

var result = await tcs.Task;

if (result.Item2 == false)
        {
            var errors = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(result.Item1, new { error    = "" });

            return false;
        }
```

Then i am getting above error sometimes not all the time.

What is the scenario?

Can anyone tell?`

Comment: your ContactNumber is never empty?

Comment: It can be.but it is not the problem.